# Comparar valores obtenidos de la misma consulta

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, linq

Soy nueva en C#, estoy realizando una aplicación web en VisualStudio 2015, con ASP.NET MVC5 y EF6.
Necesito comparar los valores que me arroja una consulta en linq, normalmente lo haría con un dos `for`, uno dentro del otro, aunque a lo mejor me puedan sugerir una forma más óptima de hacerlo. Mi problema es que cuando realizo el `for` no tengo forma de obtener el valor que necesito comparar.
**Controller**

```
var query_y_axis = db.registro.Select(o => new { o.value, o.date});
var minutes = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < query_y_axis .LongCount()-1; i++)
{
    minutes = db.registro.  //AQUI NO OBTENGO EL CAMPO POR EL QUE DESEO COMPARAR QUE ES DATE
}
```

Mi intención es obtener el campo fecha (**date**), y en `minutes` almacenar el minuto de esa fecha, e ir comparando con los demás datos de esa misma consulta. y Al final obtener sólo los valores que sean en el mismo minuto.

Por ejemplo, si obtengo una lista

> **2018-02-13 10:04:01,2018-02-13 10:04:02, 2018-02-13 10:04:50, 2018-02-13 10:04:59,** 2018-02-13 10:05:06, 2018-02-13 10:05:17, 2018-02-13 10:05:23

de esta lista iría comparando el primero con los demás y me quedaria posteriormente otra lista con los primeros 4 valores que son los que tienen el mismo minuto que la fecha inicial

> (2018-02-13 10:04:01, 2018-02-13 10:04:02, 2018-02-13 10:04:50,
>   2018-02-13 10:04:59)

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar `query_y_axis`, que es el resultado de tu consulta. Usa un `foreach` en lugar de un `for`, y así podrás acceder a las propiedades que has definido:

```
foreach (var reg in query_y_axis)
{
    minutes=reg.date;
}
```

**Edit**

Para la segunda parte de tu pregunta, en realidad no es necesario usar un bucle, para eso tenemos LINQ al rescate. Aunque hablas del mismo minuto, imagino que debe ser también la misma fecha y hora.Simplemente, filtramos los resultados con `Where` y comparamos la fecha,hora y minutos de todos los elementos con la fecha,hora y minutos del primer elemento:

```
var query_y_axis = db.registro.Select(o => new { o.value, o.date});
var mismominuto = query_y_axis.Where(x => x.date.Date== query_y_axis.First().date.Date &&
                                          x.date.Hour == query_y_axis.First().date.Hour &&
                                          x.date.Minute == query_y_axis.First().date.Minute);
```

Comment: @pikho si, eso lo se hacer, porque lo tengo implementado en oto momento, pero como podria compar los valores, modifique la pregunta con ejemplo de lo que necesito.

Comment: @Mary bueno, la pregunta original no tenía nada que ver con lo que has puesto después. De todas maneras, no se si lo entiendo. La cuestión es que en `query_y_axis` obtienes los campos `value` y `date` de todos los registros. Lo que quieres es obtener todos los registros que estén en el mismo minuto que el primero de los registros encontrados?

Comment: si así mismo, realmente todo es mas complicado pero si, es obtener solamente los registros que estén en el mismo minuto que el primero de los registros encontrados

Comment: me da el sigiuente error `{"The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."}`

Comment: @Mary Algo está mal en tu código.  `Date` es una propiedad de todos los objetos `DateTime`, asi que el problema debe ser que `date` en tus registros no es de ese tipo. Es un string por casualidad?

Comment: si, es de tipo datetime, por eso es que no se porque sale el error

Comment: Pon un punto de depuración despues de tu consulta `var query_y_axis = db.registro.Select...` y comprueba que datos te está devolviendo, para asegurarte de que `date` es un datetime. Yo he hecho una prueba, y el código que te he puesto funciona correctamente.